# Unable to access SSRS 2016 portal externally

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have installed SSRS 2016 on windows 2012 server R2. The SQL server 2016 is configured correctly and TCP enabled. It seems like I can not access the report portal from my machine using my network ID even though I can access it from some servers that are hosted on the same cloud.

I have been trying to find out a reason or a clue but I am really out of ideas. The firewall of the server is disabled and the windows service of SSRS is running under a service account as well as the SQL server instance.

I opened up the service exe file from VS to get more trace logs as the log file doesn't have any error to indicate or direct me on warning or error message unlike the verbose entries I got from the service Console application. Please let me know if you have encountered or seen anything like that before .. I am really puzzled and going nuts !!

> Info    - 4:22:55 PM - Setting up Debug CRT libraries
>
> Warning - 4:22:55 PM - %_NTDRIVE% not defined... Skipping
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Starting ReportServerWebApp
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Working directory : C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\MSRS13.SQL16\Reporting Services\RSWebApp
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Report Server url:
>   http://localhost:80/reportsdemo
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Report Server Web App virtual root:
>   /DemoReports
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Web app url: http://+:80/DemoReports/
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Authentication scheme(s): Ntlm
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 0    : AuthSchemeConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 5    : RequestLoggingConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 10   : CustomAuthenticationConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 20   : BasicAuthenticationConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 25   : RequestThrottlingConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 30   : CsrfTokenCreationConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 40   : LanguageConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 50   : XFrameOptionsConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 50   : ClassicUrlRedirecterConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 50   : PopulateHeadersConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 53   : LocalRequestMiddlewareConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 55   : ClassicUrlRewriterConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 100  : FileSystemConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 190  : ServiceUnavailableConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 200  : DatabaseAvailableConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 300  : CsrfTokenValidationConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:56 PM - Registering 500  : WebApiOwinConfig
>
> Info    - 4:22:57 PM - Registering 600  : ODataWebApiOwinConfig
>
> Verbose - 4:23:02 PM - [nh78byvq]: Request received
>
> Warning - 4:23:02 PM - [nh78byvq]: CSRF Token not generated due to
>   exception:
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.CannotValidateEncryptedDataException:
>   The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted
>   data in the database.
>
> Verbose - 4:23:03 PM - [nh78byvq]: 10.206.197.30: GET /index.html -
>   Response 304- 0:00:00.1191454
>
> Verbose - 4:23:03 PM - [r0eyb35z]: Request received
>
> Warning - 4:23:03 PM - [r0eyb35z]: CSRF Token not generated due to
>   exception:\n
>
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.CannotValidateEncryptedDataException:
>   The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted
>   datain the database.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I've deleted all encrypted content and regenerated my key's and I still get the same error.